# PHP reading fscanf

Tags: php, scanf

I have been trying to read numbers from online course with given input as STDIN and my file is like this:

```
2
3 15
```

I read the 2 and 3, how can I read 15?

my code:

```
    <?php
    /*
    // Sample code to perform I/O:
    
    fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $name);           // Reading input from STDIN
    echo "Hi, ".$name.".\n";                // Writing output to STDOUT
    
    // Warning: Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data to output will cause the test cases to fail
    */
    
    // Write your code here
    fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $amount);
    echo $amount . "\n";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $amount; $i++)
{
    fscanf(STDIN, "%s", $x);
    echo $x . "\n";
}
    ?>
```

My output now is: 2 3 3 and I want 2 3 15

Comment: How would you modify the example on the [documentation page for `fscanf`](http://php.net/fscanf) to fit your problem?

Comment: That is why i asked..

Comment: Ok, but have you put a bit of thought into it? I mean, they use tabs. It's not a stretch to test what you should use instead, there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fscanf` works on lines, but `%s` in default stop reading on space. Use:

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%[^\n]", $x);
```

and explode `$x` by spaces

Comment: Can You comment what is this meaning that you put instead of %s?

Comment: You do not need the s at the end

Comment: It looks like the example on php.net was a bit inaccurate, and this entry is a regular expression that tells you how to read the input. (previously `fscanf(STDIN, "%[^\n]s", $x);`)

Comment: It means: any string that starts with `\n`, so it kinda omits the new lines or how then fscanf works here?

Comment: No `^` has two meanings. The second one is always used in `[]` (alternatives) and means *everything except* (in this case `\n`) And this is a simplified "regular expression".

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to nudge you to was to use a space in your format string and read your input into separate variables, like this.

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%s %s", $a, $b);
echo $a . ' ' . $b . "\n";
```

Comment: Your solution assumes that there will be max 2 numbers in a line.